# Why is it necessary to pass existing arguments to `setTimeout` again?

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing

Why is it necessary to write `a` and `b` after `mls` in the `setTimeout` method here? Aren’t `a` and `b` already defined in the arrow function?

```js
function f(a, b) {
  alert(a + b);
}

// shows 3 after 1 second
Function.prototype.defer = function(mls) {
  return (a, b) => setTimeout(this, mls, a, b);
}

f.defer(1000)(1, 2);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "already defined"? The arrow function declares its parameters, yes, but if you don't use them…

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) takes a variable number of arguments. The first one is the function (`this`, or `f` in this case), the second one is the delay. Any argument after that is *passed to the to-be-called function* upon calling it.

Your function `f` expects two arguments; if they aren’t passed, they are `undefined`. There are indeed an *“`a` and `b` already defined in the arrow function”*, but they are *scoped to the arrow function*. If a function calls another function, its arguments aren’t automatically transfered.

Internally, `setTimeout` is doing something like `outerWorking` in this example:

```
const inner = (a, b) => a + b,
  outerWorking = (a, b) => inner(a, b),
  outerNotWorking = (a, b) => inner();

console.log(outerWorking(2, 3)); // 5
console.log(outerNotWorking(2, 3)); // NaN
```

So `f.defer(1000)` returns a new function with `mls === 1000` and `this === f`. It accepts `a` and `b` which are yet to be defined with the next function call (calling the arrow functions, with the argument list `(1, 2)`). Only when you pass `a`, `b` at `f.defer(1000)(1, 2)`, then `setTimeout(this, mls,a,b)` will be called with `a === 1`, `b === 2` and the other two bindings above (`this` and `delay`).

Alternatively, this could be written as

```
Function.prototype.defer = function(mls, a, b){
  setTimeout(this, mls, a, b);
};

f.defer(1000, 1, 2)
```

But there’s an advantage in the original, *curried* approach, as you can simply detach the “defered function” from the final call:

```
const add1sDelay = f.defer(1000);

add1sDelay(1, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `f.defer(1000)` returns the arrow function which in turn gets called with `(1,2)` as parameter. This arrow function is calling `setTimeout` which is supposed to call the same `function f` with these parameters `1` and `2`. And the definition of `seTimeout` states that you can pass parameter to the callback function after first 2 parameters. Please refer below definition and link for the reference.

```
window.setTimeout(function[, delay, param1, param2, ...]);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Answer (score -1):

The arrow function is defining a function that then invokes `setTimeout(this, mls, a, b)`. It could also be written as:

```
Function.prototype.defer = function(mls){
    var that = this;
    return function(a,b) {
        setTimeout(that, mls, a, b);
    }
}
```

This is important to note because you're actually returning a function from `defer`. So when you call `f.defer(1000)`, the return value is a function - your arrow function, to be specific - and then you invoke that function with the values `1` and `2` when you call `f.defer(1000)(1, 2);`.

If you don't, your function will not be called with any parameters. These parameters are passed into the originally invoked function.

Comment: For completeness it could be included that [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ro/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) receives after the second argument (the delay time in miliseconds) _N_ (optional) params (`a` and `b` in this case).

Comment: i know that but the code does not work when you write setTimeout(this, mls) only and i dont undesrtand why

Comment: @goga Try running the code with three parameters and see what you get. Maybe that will illustrate why it will not work without the additional parameters.

Comment: @goga because `setTimeout(this, mls)` does not provide the arguments `a` and `b` required by the function

Comment: @lealceldeiro Correct, the original function `f` needs two parameters to behave correctly. Without these you will get nonsensical answers, either `NaN` or `0`.

Comment: Just in case anyone follwed the link I posted for `setTimeout` previously [this is the English version](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)